# Converting an array of hexadecimal to decimal numbers Intel 8086 Assembly Language

Tags: intel, x86-16, microprocessors, emu8086

The following is my code. The block in hex2dec works successfully for  converting a single hexadecimal number to decimal number. It would be really helpful if someone could point out where I was going wrong in the use of array. Thanks.

```
DATA SEGMENT
    NUM DW 1234H,9H,15H
    RES DB 3*10 DUP ('$','$','$')
    SIZE DB 3
DATA ENDS

CODE SEGMENT
    ASSUME DS:DATA, CS:CODE
START:
    MOV AX, DATA
    MOV DS,AX
    MOV DI,0
  LOOP3:
    MOV AX,NUM[DI]
    LEA SI,RES[DI]
    CALL HEX2DEC
    LEA DX,RES[DI]
    MOV AH,9
    INT 21H
    INC DI
    CMP DI,3
    JL LOOP3
    MOV AH,4CH   ; end program
    INT 21H
CODE ENDS

HEX2DEC PROC NEAR
    MOV CX,0
    MOV BX,10
  LOOP1:
    MOV DX,0
    DIV BX
    ADD DL,30H
    PUSH DX
    INC CX
    CMP AX,9
    JG LOOP1
    ADD AL,30H
    MOV [SI],AL
  LOOP2:
    POP AX
    INC SI
    MOV [SI],AL
    LOOP LOOP2
    RET
HEX2DEC ENDP
END START
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> MOV AX,NUM[DI]
> LEA SI,RES[DI]
> LEA DX,RES[DI]
> ```

You are treating `DI` as an array index like we use in any of the high level languages. In assembly programming we only use **displacements** aka **offsets** in the array.

In your program, since the *NUM* array is composed of words, you need to give the `DI` register successively the values 0, 2, and 4.

```
ADD  DI, 2
CMP  DI, 6
JB   LOOP3
```

Also it would be best to not treat the *RES* as an array. Just consider it a buffer and always use it from the start.

```
RES  DB  10 DUP (0)
...
LEA  SI, RES
CALL HEX2DEC
LEA  DX, RES
```

---

A better version of *HEX2DEC* avoids the ugly prefixed "0" on the single digit numbers:

```
HEX2DEC PROC NEAR
    XOR  CX, CX        <--- Same as MOV CX,0
    MOV  BX,10
LOOP1:
    XOR  DX, DX        <--- Same as MOV DX,0
    DIV  BX
    ADD  DL, 30H
    PUSH DX
    INC  CX
    TEST AX, AX
    JNZ  LOOP1
LOOP2:
    POP  AX
    MOV  [SI], AL
    INC  SI
    LOOP LOOP2
    MOV  AL, "$"       <--- Add this to use DOS function 09h
    MOV  [SI], AL
    RET
HEX2DEC ENDP
```

Comment: I replaced the INC DI with ADD as suggested by you and also changed RES so that it always operates like a buffer. Still it gave the wrong answer.

Comment: Did you terminate the string with a **$** character for each output?

Comment: Are you sure that your assembler doesn't require you to write `MOV AX, @DATA` `MOV DS,AX` ? So adding the **@**.

Comment: Thanks. The update to the HEX2DEC really helped it work. Still have to figure out why though. Guess that will take some time  1 doubt though. What purpose does the 'TEST AX, AX' serve in the function?

Comment: The `test ax, ax` instruction is functionally the same as `cmp ax, 0`. You could have written: `CMP AX, 0` `JNE LOOP1` for looping as long as the `ax` not being zero. (Just like in your original question where you looped just as long the `ax` was greater than 9)